# WebStorm looks like is importing not exported vars from js files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

Create file `ownerId.js`

```
  hello
  hello2
  const xxx = 2
```

Create file some.js

```
  const hello = 2;

  xxx
```

Ctrl hover the `xxx` or the `hello` variable and then click, they redirect between each other.

So basically the problem is that I have a ts file, and a random js files. Somehow TypeScript doesn't even fail because some random js file specifies that variable.

Comment: What's the problem? The file without any exports or imports is just a script, and all its variables are in global scope, so WebStorm seems to do all right.

Comment: no, that's not true. To put in global you need to do `window.global = 5`. The script fails if I run from typescript because var not found. If what you say is true, I'd have 10000 global vars in my project, so is completely not true.

Comment: It might be assuming that it's global because it would be in normal JavaScript, but maybe typscript guards against that (not too familiar with typescript). Alternatively, I know that Ruby mine shows things named the same because it can't quite tell what your file has included or not, slash just to guarantee that you are aware of all the possible things that you could be referencing (useful if something goes wrong and it's using the wrong thing), so I imagine it could be something similar in webstorm. It's just showing you all the variables of the same name.

Comment: What really matters isn't if webstorm shows you it, it's whether the value is what you expect it to be (undefined)

Comment: just as @Cerberus noted above, your vars belong to a global scope as the file is not considered a module (doesn't have export/import declarations). In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. This means that within the browser `var something` defines a new global variable. In Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; `var something` inside a Node.js module will be local to that module

Comment: In webstorm shows the value from the other file. So he refrences that value. Come on, this doesn't make sense, nobody would be able to develop anything serious in webstorm if all variables are global by default, imagine would be a complete mess. It never happened to me before, maybe is a setting that changed or a bug.

Comment: TypeScript assumes that a file without imports or exports runs in the global scope.  Whether that is actually true depends on your build system and runtime environment.  If your environment treats files as modules even if they have no imports or exports, you can clue TypeScript in about that by adding a dummy `export {};` statement to each file.  Or if a file doesn't have any type declarations that you want to use, you can try excluding it in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: but in the example above I put 2 js files. Anyway still don't think makes any sense, because if you are adding ts to an existing project with js would be a mess. I had before js and ts and just js and it never had all vars exported as globals in all my other files.